Vert.x is catching java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, not allowing the heap dump to be captured
I'm dealing with a legacy service (Java 8, vertx-core: 3.9.16). I'm receiving java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I cannot capture a heap dump automatically. I suspect it's because this exception might be caught by .exceptionally operator somewhere down the stack (this operator is used 200+ times in the project). I added -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to my JVM args but it's not helping.
I get these logs:
LOGGER.rcCatching(...): catching - throwable message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    protected CompletableFuture<RenderingContext> loadContentFormat(RenderingContext ctx) {
        final RuntimeContext rc = ctx.getRuntimeContext();
        LOGGER.rcEntry(rc, ctx.getId());
        
        final CompletableFuture<DeliveryRenderingDataContext> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
        final String cacheKey = getCacheKey(rc, "content", ctx.getId());

        LOGGER.rcTrace(rc, deliverySearchLRUCache.get(cacheKey) != null ? "cache hit for content by id {}" : "cachemiss for content by id {}", cacheKey);

        deliverySearchLRUCache.computeIfAbsent(cacheKey, (k) -> dataAccessor.searchSingleDeliveryItemDocumentById(rc, "content", ctx.getId(), ctx.isRestrictedInvocation()))
            .thenAccept(deliveryItemJson -> {
                if (deliveryItemJson == null) {
                    ItemNotFoundException e = new ItemNotFoundException("content", ctx.getId());
                    result.completeExceptionally(e);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.debug("Loaded content: {}",  StringUtil.truncateObject(deliveryItemJson, 512));
                    ctx.setItemJson(deliveryItemJson);
                    result.complete(ctx);
                } 
            })
            .exceptionally(th -> {
                LOGGER.rcCatching(rc, th);
                result.completeExceptionally(th);
                return null;}
            );
        return LOGGER.rcExit(rc, result);
    }

I wonder if this error handling is implemented correctly as I'm not familiar with Vert.x at all and if there's some straightforward approach to fix this without editing the code in over 200 places.
I added -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option to JVM args. So far I only managed to capture the heap dump manually.

The code above looks like Java async API, not Vert.x. For example, exceptionally is a method defined by CompletionStage: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-

That being said, catching exceptions does not prevent the JVM from generating heap dumps. Have you tried to specify the heap dump location with the -XX:HeapDumpPath option?

@OliverMarienfeld No, I haven't - I thought there was a default one. Thanks for suggestion, I'll try to specify the path.
